# REP-501: Unable to connect to the specified database.

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I need to implement the functionality of generating a report from some parameters that the user introduces through an Oracle Forms application.

The utility is built into a code unit inside the form:

```
PACKAGE BODY INVOICES_MANAGEMENT IS
  -- Generate Invoices Report
    PROCEDURE GENERATE_INVOICES_REPORT (
        P_REPORTNAME IN VARCHAR2,
        P_FORMAT IN VARCHAR2,
        P_REPORT_SERVER IN VARCHAR2,
        P_MINYEAR IN INTEGER, 
        P_MAXYEAR IN INTEGER) IS

            v_report_id Report_Object;
            -- Unique id for each Report request
            v_report_server_job VARCHAR2(100); 
            -- Status of the Report job
            v_rep_status VARCHAR2(100);
            --  job_id as number only string
            v_job_id VARCHAR2(100);
            -- Param List
            v_tmp_plid ParamList; 

            v_hidden_action VARCHAR2(200);
        BEGIN

            v_tmp_plid := Get_Parameter_List('RepData');

                    IF NOT ID_NULL(v_tmp_plid) THEN
                        DESTROY_PARAMETER_LIST( v_tmp_plid );
                    END IF;

                    v_tmp_plid := CREATE_PARAMETER_LIST ('RepData');

            -- Get a handle to the Report Object
            v_report_id := FIND_REPORT_OBJECT(P_REPORTNAME);

            /* Define the report output format and the name of the Reports Server as well as a user-defined parameter. */
            SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(v_report_id, REPORT_DESFORMAT, P_FORMAT);
            SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(v_report_id, REPORT_DESTYPE, CACHE);
            SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(v_report_id, REPORT_COMM_MODE, SYNCHRONOUS);
            SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(v_report_id, REPORT_SERVER, P_REPORT_SERVER);
            --SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(v_report_id, REPORT_OTHER, 'MIN_YEAR='||P_MINYEAR||' MAX_YEAR=' || P_MAXYEAR || ' paramform=no');


                    Add_Parameter(v_tmp_plid, 'MIN_YEAR', TEXT_PARAMETER, P_MINYEAR );
                    Add_Parameter(v_tmp_plid, 'MAX_YEAR', TEXT_PARAMETER, P_MAXYEAR );

                    v_hidden_action :=  'userid=' ||
                            --get_application_property(username)
                            'sergio11' || '/' ||
                            --get_application_property(password)
                            'bisite00' || '@' || 'XE';
                            --get_application_property(connect_string);

                 MESSAGE('HIDE ACTION -> ' || v_hidden_action);

                    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (v_report_id, REPORT_OTHER, v_hidden_action); 

            -- Run Report
            v_report_server_job := RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(v_report_id, v_tmp_plid);

            v_job_id := substr(v_report_server_job, instr(v_report_server_job, '_' , -1)+1);

            LOOP
                        v_rep_status := REPORT_OBJECT_STATUS(v_report_server_job);
                        EXIT WHEN v_rep_status IN ('FINISHED', 'TERMINATED_WITH_ERROR');
            END LOOP;

            IF v_rep_status = 'FINISHED' THEN
                /* Call the Reports output to be displayed in the browser. The URL for relative addressing is valid
                only when the Reports Server resides on the same host as the Forms Server and is accessed via the same port.
                For accessing a remote Reports environment, you must use a fully qualified URL (i.e. http://hostname:port ) */
                WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT ('/reports/rwservlet/getjobid'|| v_job_id || '?server='|| P_REPORT_SERVER, '_blank');
            ELSE
                MESSAGE('Report failed with error message '|| v_rep_status);
            END IF;

    END;
END;
```

This procedure will be executed when using the "Generate" button, then the user should be able to download the pdf file with the list of invoices.

[image: invoices_report]

Next I expose the code for SmartTrigger **'WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED'**

```
DECLARE

        v_minyear INTEGER;
        v_maxyear INTEGER;

        v_reportname VARCHAR2(30) DEFAULT 'INVOICES_REPORT';
        v_format VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'PDF';
        v_reportserver VARCHAR2(15) DEFAULT 'rep_ie8win7';


BEGIN

    v_minyear := :MIN_YEAR_TEXT;
    v_maxyear := :MAX_YEAR_TEXT;

    -- Generate Invoice Report
    INVOICES_MANAGEMENT.GENERATE_INVOICES_REPORT ( v_reportname, v_format, 
        v_reportserver, v_minyear, v_maxyear);

END;
```

The answer is immediate, **"FRM - 41214 Unable to run report"** is throw with a **TERMINATED_WITH_ERRORS** state.

When consulting the status of the "job" launched from the Oracle Forms application, I find that the source of the problem is an error **"REP-501: Unable to connect to the specified database."**

[image]

**Considerations**

- I have a TNS_ADMIN environment variable configured to locate the
  files for the **Oracle NET layer (tnsnames.ora)**

**TNS_ADMIN -> C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN**

- From Oracle Reports Builder I can correctly generate the report, I
  have exported this report as a binary file **".rep"** to include it as a
  "report" object in the form.
- I have tried to provide the complete connection string through the
  **userid** parameter.

  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (v_report_id, REPORT_OTHER, 'userid=' || get_application_property(username) || '/' || get_application_property(password) || '@' || get_application_property(connect_string));

I am using Oracle Application Server 10g.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: what do you get when you issue `tnsping XE` in the `DOS` screen?

Comment: In the Oracle Home for the REPORTS server, there should be a WLS_REPORTS.log under your DOMAIN_HOME/servers/WLS_REPORTS/logs folder. This should have more detailed information about why your reports server can't connect to the database while your forms server can.

Comment: when I do a tnsping XE I get ->  Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.
1)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (20 msec)

Comment: @Zynon thanks for the comment.
In the log files I do not see any message that in more detail about the error

Comment: Well, did you add `TNS_ADMIN` for `user`(may be Sergio.Sanchez, i.e. upper) part of the env. variables or for `system`(lower part) of the env. variables? Should be added for `user` env. params. of Windows.